# Least expensive method to traverse array data

Tags: php

I have an array of Users and Department Groups as under:

```
**users:**
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => John
            [City] => New York
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Amy
            [City] => San Francisco
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Jacob
            [City] => Seattle
        )
)

**departmentgroups**
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => HR
            [member] => Array
                (
                    [0] => John
                    [1] => Jake
                    [2] => Amy
                    [3] => Mark
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Finance
            [member] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Jacob
                    [1] => John
                    [2] => Amy
                    [3] => David
                    [4] => Ramone
                )

        )
)
```

I need to print all users in the users array along with their departments by traversing through these 2 arrays. So, my initial reaction is to loop through the users array and then for each user, loop through departments array and return the department name. If they belong to multiple departments, a department array will be returned.

I found that this kind of traversing is very expensive and takes a while, if I have a list of 20000 users and 30000 department groups.

Is there a quick way to do this instead of the for loops?

Comment: is this data already in a db? seems like it would be better to create a query that groups them

Comment: no.. the data is in arrays. It comes from an API

Comment: also, holy crap, 30000 departments? really? I did not know such a business could exist with that many depts

Comment: departments is just an example.. :) It's actually something else in my code, but the array structure is the same :)

Comment: Is `name` unique in the users array? how about first walking through that array and make the name the top level key, then loop through your 2nd array and just reference the first array by the top level key (name)

Comment: yeah.. "name" is unique in the users array.

Comment: okay so just loop through first array and restructure it to be like like `$array1['name']=array('city'=> 'city')` and then loop through the 2nd array and use the `['member'][$i]` value as the array key for first array, as you loop through the 2nd array

Comment: hmm.. I can try that, but not sure if it will lessen the cost. Is there a way to do this using php's array functions?

Comment: I can think of ways to make it more "one liner" style and less using an actual loop, but there's no magic bullet php function that can do what you want with your structure as-is, without help that will effectively make it no more efficient than just looping and breaking when found. If anything that way ^^ is more efficient because it's cutting out sorting algorithms and just having a single loop. And then you're directly referencing by name. For sure, it's a lot more efficient than looping through the first array looking for a name every single iteration of the 2nd loop, and tbh..

Comment: .. I can't really think of a more efficient way, short of putting the data into a db and then running a query, which may or may not take longer. Which, if it's destined to go in a db anyways, then it might be worth going that route

Comment: okay.. Thanks for the help.. I will implement your suggestion and see how it goes for me.

Comment: well, i'm not the brightest crayon in the box.. perhaps someone smarter than me can chime in ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: There is no efficient way. Don't bother to read this essay I just wrote, I just didn't want to throw it away ;)

## Big O notation

Well, I definately wasn't the smartest student back in university but what I remember is, that we had the "[Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation%20Big%20O%20notation)" when it came to complexity.

So let's try to discuss, what you are trying to do. I have one array `Users` of size *n* and another array `Departments` of size *m*.

What you want is an association between `Users` and `Departmens` and as you stated, you "need to print all users in the users array along with their departments". So you have at least a complexity of *n* (since you need all users in the `Users` array).

Now we have a look at the `departments` array. As we can see from your example, John in in HR as well as in Finance. So a user may work for several departments. This means, what a shame, that we always have to loop through the whole `departments` to make sure, we don't miss one of the departments the user is working for. We remember, the `departments` array is of size *m*.

So, for every user we have to loop through *m* items in `departments`. For the first user *m* items, for the second user *m* items, etc. Since we have *n* users, our complexity is `O(n*m)`.

This is, as you might have noticed, never efficient! And there is no array function in the world, not even in another language, that could make this more efficient.

Or course, I don't know all your use cases. If you have to compile this list only once, I suggest you do it this way. Every "optimization" might introduce errors and make your code harder to debug.

If you are not familiar with complexity in Big O notation, think about this the following, I call it

## The database way

You have one table with all the users and one table with all the departments. Since one user may be in many departments and one department may have many users, you will have a connection table like `user_id | department_id`, let's call it `users_to_departments`. Of course, you might think, your `users_to_departments` table will definately be smaller than `n*m`. But to fill it, you will first have to add all users to table `users` and then, while filling table `departments`, you will have to look for the user's id in `users`.

But stop, you said the user names are unique! So use this "name" field as what I called `user_id` and here we go, we saved us from looking for each user in the `users` table.

Now you can do a simple `SELECT * FROM users_to_departments ud JOIN users u ON u.id = ud.user_id JOIN departments d ON d.id = ud.department_id ORDER BY ud.user_id, ud.department_id` to get you list. Just remember, a user will be in the list `x` times, when in `x` departments.

## Conclusion

And, if you ask me, I don't think this will be faster since you have to transfer all your data from the webservice to your database, request it from the database and transform its response. For me, that sounds only more prone to errors and not even more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/array_merge_recursive) function. You may need to increase the memory usage in the php.ini settings.